# How do I implement navigation button like Echofon for iPhone does?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, navigationcontroller

[image: navigation button]

Hi, how do I implement navigation button like Echofon does, especially with those icons (like Home, Messages) on the button ? I am new to iPhone development so I am really appreciated if someone can paste some code samples or point to me some tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: It's called UITabBar. See [UITabBar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks. I know this must be a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is called a tab bar view controller, and you can find a good tutorial on how to create an app using it [here](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/)

Comment: Hi I chose this one b/c the link you provided talking about how to build UITabBarController with UINavigationController. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create Tab Based Application for it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a great tutorial.](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/09/28/uitabbar-iphone-tutorial/) You need to create a tab based application. It's pretty simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

All，

Thanks for answering my dumb question. I found that the Chapter 6 "Multiview applications" of "Beginning
iPhone 4 Development" gives a very good explanation of all kinds of mutiview app.